# Unable to alter PCL library Target Frameworks

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

I am running Visual Studio 2012 plus Xamarin.iOS with the latest version of each.  I have Portable Class Libraries in which I want to select the latest "Xamarin.iOS" release as a build target (instead of MonoTouch).  In Visual Studio I open up the Project's Properties, select the Library tab, and click on Change under Target Frameworks.  However, I am unable to modify any of the checkboxes.  Any checkbox I change instantly closes the "Change Target Frameworks" dialog.  If I change one of the dropdowns (for example, change from .NET 4.0+ to 4.5) then when I go to click OK the changes do not get reflected in the Target Frameworks list.

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Had you made any changes to the portable profiles yourself to support Xamarin before the official support came out?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this by changing the TargetFrameworkProfile in the XML of the csproj file.  I was on Profile104 which is no longer supported, so I manually removed this and left this blank in the XML, and then was able to re-add the profile targets (after using the dialog it put me on Profile136).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem , while trying to add MvvmCross Nuget Package. I've to change PCL profile to 259 , it didn't allow me ( Xamarin Studio on iOS) , Ok and Cancel buttons are not present.

- I opened the .csproj file in TextEditor.
- Removed the PCL profile information. Reopened the project.It gave me build error.
- So added following string manually
  Profile259

It Started working.Hope this information helps.