# Can PCLs created in Visual Studio be used in Xamarin projects?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

I created a Portable Class Library the other day in VS2013. It targeted the following platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8.1
- Windows Phone 8.1 (non-Silverlight)

My question is, can this be used in Xamarin projects such as Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android? I've found a project claiming to support Xamarin, but grepping the solution and project files for `"ios"` and `"android"` turn up nothing. If not, what can I do to make my library portable to those platforms?

Thanks.

Comment: **Yes**. *Portable Class Libraries* are, by definition, *portable*. You won't find platform specific code in them. What is your question?

Comment: @HighCore My platform only **targets** the above platforms, not Xamarin. Will it be able to be used on Xamarin.iOS or Android?

Comment: yes, simply change the target platforms, and rebuild.

Comment: @HighCore I get what you are saying. The problem is, Visual Studio provides no such functionality since targeting Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android are part of Xamarin Studio.

Comment: If you examine the *.csproj* file, which PCL profile (XML tag `<TargetFrameworkProfile>`) are you targeting? Given the above platforms I would guess 111. Profile 111 implicitly also targets *Xamarin iOS* and *Android*, so even if it is not explicitly indicated the class library can be consumed by iOS and Android as long as it is a profile 111 library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to install Xamarin for Visual Studio first if you haven't already
2. Open your PCL project and change the target profile to include the Xamarin platforms you want to support. (e.g. Profile 78)
3. Optionally retarget all your dependencies (projects/nugets)
4. Recompile your PCLs

You should now have dlls that work also in Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make your project target those platforms and then recompile your .dlls in order to make them available for Android and iOS.

I don't know what is the edition of your Visual Studio, but the options to target Android/iOS should be available in VS2013. In any case, try downloading Visual Studio 2015 community (which is free), open your project using it and the option should be there.

If none of this works, you can also try manually changing your .`csproj` file to a different profile. This is stated to have worked on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20010054/3465182).